# neo4j: How to load CSV using conditional correctly?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

What I am trying to do is to import a dataset with a tree data structure inside from CSV to neo4j. Nodes are stored along with their parent node and depth level (max 6) in the tree. So I try to check depth level using `CASE` and then add a node to its parent like this (creating a node just for 1st level so far for testing purpose):

```
export FILEPATH=file:///Example.csv

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM {FILEPATH} AS line
WITH DISTINCT line,
line.`Level` AS level,
line.`ParentCodeID_Cal` AS parentCode,
line.`CodeSet` AS codeSet,
line.`Category` AS nodeCategory,
line.`Type` AS nodeType, 
line.`L1code` AS l1Code, line.`L1Description` AS l1Description, line.`L1Name` AS l1Name, line.`L1NameAb` AS l1NameAb,
line.`L2code` AS l2Code, line.`L2Description` AS l2Description, line.`L2Name` AS l2Name, line.`L2NameAb` AS l2NameAb,
line.`L3code` AS l3Code, line.`L3Description` AS l3Description, line.`L3Name` AS l3Name, line.`L3NameAb` AS l3NameAb,
line.`L1code` AS l4Code, line.`L4Description` AS l4Description, line.`L4Name` AS l4Name, line.`L4NameAb` AS l4NameAb,
line.`L1code` AS l5Code, line.`L5Description` AS l5Description, line.`L5Name` AS l5Name, line.`L5NameAb` AS l5NameAb,
line.`L1code` AS l6Code, line.`L6Description` AS l6Description, line.`L6Name` AS l6Name, line.`L6NameAb` AS l6NameAb,
codeSet + parentCode AS nodeId
CASE line.`Level` 
    WHEN '1' THEN CREATE (n0:Node{id:nodeId, description:l1Description, name:l1Name, nameAb:l1NameAb, category:nodeCategory, type:nodeType}) 
    ELSE 
END;
```

But I get this result:

> WARNING: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 17, column 3 (offset:
>   982)) "CASE level "    ^

I'm aware there is a mistake at syntax.

I'm using neo4j 3.0.4 & Windows 10 (using neo4j shell running it with `D:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.0.4\bin>java -classpath neo4j-desktop-3.0.4.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors. For example, a `CASE` clause cannot contain a  `CREATE` clause.

In any case, you should be able to greatly simplify your Cypher. For example, this might suit your needs:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM {FILEPATH} AS line
WITH DISTINCT line, ('l' + line.Level) AS prefix
CREATE (:Node{
  id: line.CodeSet + line.ParentCodeID_Cal,
  description: line[prefix + 'Description'],
  name: line[prefix + 'Name'],
  nameAb: line[prefix + 'NameAb'],
  category: line.Category,
  type: line.Type})
```